# Regarding assigning model data to textbox in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i am new in MVC. i got a code and it was just about to populate viewdata from controller and pass it to view. just have look at the code.

**controller**

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            ViewData["Name"] = "My name is XYZ";
            return View();
        }
```

**view page**

```
@Html.TextBox("Name")
```

my question is how textbox understand to extract name and display it as textbox value. basically name was stored in viewdata. first we need to extarct data from viewdata and then we can assign that data to textbox as value. how it works ?.

some one explain but things is not very clear to me

MVC is designed with default protocol to look for keywords and try to make associations to those keywords.  You've chosen to use 'Name' for a temporary data object.  MVC will then make an effort to look for any elements that have the same name.  it believes that you intended to assign the element the same name as your ViewData object because you want it associated.

The same goes for ViewBag.  You can give a ViewBag a name (ViewBag.Name) and any time you use 'Name' for an element, MVC will automatically assume you want that element associated to the ViewBag data.  This works with lists too!

```
ViewBag.myList = db.Products.ToList();

@Html.DropDownList("myList");
```

my understand about mvc flow is not very clear.i am new in mvc. so i am reading mvc tutorial. i am not very much convienced after reading the above answer. just think about asp.net web form. in asp.net web form

if we store anything into viewstate or session like this way `viewstate["Name"]="Mou" or session["Name"]="Mou"` then we need render that value at client side like this way `<asp:textbox value=<% name %>/>` then i will get error but if we write like this way `<asp:textbox value=<% viewstate["Name"] as string %>/>` then it will work. so how MVC can understand if we specify simply `@Html.TextBox("Name")`

suppose name can be stored in session, viewdata, viewbag, tempdata etc so how MVC engine can resolve it ? looking for good explanation with more example.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> my question is how textbox understand to extract name and display it as textbox value.

It's all magic strings. You have placed the `Name` key into the `ViewData`:

```
ViewData["Name"] = "My name is XYZ";
```

So when you use `@Html.TextBox("Name")` the helper will search for the Name key in ViewData and automatically bind the data.

It's normal that this seems confusing to you. Don't use any ViewBag/ViewData. Use view models instead. This way you will no longer be relying on any magic strings. You will use strongly typed helpers. For example let's suppose that you wanted to bind some simple TextBox. Go ahead and write a view model for it:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

then have your controller action pass this model to the view:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{  
    var model = new MyViewModel();
    model.Name = "My name is XYZ";
    return View(model);
}
```

and finally make your view strongly typed to the model and use strongly typed helpers:

```
@model MyViewModel
...
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name)
```

You see, MVC means Model/View/Controller. It doesn't mean ViewData/View/Controller or ViewBag/View/Controller. So many people are confusing these abbreviation and completely defeating the purpose of the pattern. They are feeding data to the view from different sources, not only from the view model which is where information should be fed. Don't be like those people.

And since you talked about lists, once again writing the following is completely wrong:

```
@Html.DropDownList("myList")
```

The reason why this is completely wrong is because in order to have a dropdown you need 2 properties on the model: a simple scalar property to bind the selected value to and a collection property to bind the available values in the drop down.

Just like that:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string SelectedValue { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Values { get; set; }
}
```

which is usual is populated in your controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{  
    var model = new MyViewModel();

    // this usually comes from a database
    model.Values = new[]
    {
        new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "item 1" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "item 2" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "item 3" },
    };

    // This allows to preselect the second value in the dropdown
    model.SelectedValue = "2";

    return View(model);
}
```

and in the view:

```
@model MyViewModel
...
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedValue, Model.Values)
```

So my advice would be the sooner you forget about ViewData/ViewBag the better.

Comment: i have bit confusion about dropdown bindings. your MyViewModel has two property one is SelectedValue & another is Values so how u can write model.Value = "2"; ? there is no property called Value ? and u have not shown how to use SelectedValue property ? if possible please show me how to use SelectedValue property. thanks

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake on my part. It should have been `model.SelectedValue = "2";`. I have updated my answer to reflect this.